# printing limited characters in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, slice

I am trying to print the first three characters of every item in the list below.  However, when I run the code, all it prints is the list with no modifications three times on three different lines.  I have researched string slicing extensively and still am not sure why.

```
lst = ['January' , 'February' , 'March']

for char in lst:
   print(lst[:3])
```

Comment: try `char[:3]` instead of `lst[:3]`

Answer (score 2):

Print the name you're using to iterate, not the sequence you're iterating over.

```
for char in lst:
   print(char[:3])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're printing `lst` when you should be printing `char`.  It would help to use descriptive names like `monthList` and `month` instead, then it would be more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
>>> lst = ['January' , 'February' , 'March']
>>> print('\n'.join([s[:3] for s in lst]))
Jan
Feb
Mar
```